# How should I edit this example after knowing .clear() is deprecated?

Tags: javascript, arrays, deprecated

```
if (pool[i].alive) {
    if (pool[i].draw()) {
    pool[i].clear();
    pool.push((poolsplice(i,1))[0]);
    }
}
```

There is an array called pool and if `draw()` returns true, then `pool[i].clear()`. I searched online and found that clear was deprecated and so the new way of doing it would be to use `pool[i].open();`

Here's the my source.
[Clear Method](http://help.dottoro.com/ljcxfnth.php)

I'm following along with this tutorial http://blog.sklambert.com/html5-canvas-game-the-player-ship/

How can I get the same result?

Comment: Isn't that link quite, um, clear about it? "The clear method is deprecated and has no effect in the newer versions of commonly used browsers."

Comment: Hmm... `clear()` was, and `open()` still is a method of `document`, what exactly you have in the `pool` array?

Comment: I'm following allow with this tutorial http://blog.sklambert.com/html5-canvas-game-the-player-ship/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.clear()` method being called in that tutorial is actually a custom method defined in the `Bullet` object. If you look at the definition of `Bullet`, `clear` will reset the values of the bullet to the default:

```
this.clear = function() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.speed = 0;
    this.alive = false;
};
```

The `document.clear()` method has nothing to do with this function, so your first link is of no relevance here. Since you are defining the method yourself in the `Bullet` class, it should work no problem.

Comment: Ok so I should have been looking for a clear method for HTML5 Canvas not javascript. Thanks

Comment: Actually the `clear` method you are looking for is a method of the `Bullet` object, which is defined later on in the tutorial. I've updated my answer accordingly.